# How to overwrite event listener within prototype?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, prototype, event-listener, dom-events

I'm trying to implement two methods: start and stop. The problem is, stop doesn't seem to work.

```
const MyObj = function(x) {
    this.x = x;
};
MyObj.prototype.start = function(el) {
    el.onclick = (function() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }).bind(this);
};
MyObj.prototype.stop = function(el) {
    el.onclick = null;
};

const obj = new MyObj("x");
document.getElementById("checkbox").onchange = function() {
    if (this.value) {
        obj.start(document.body);
    }
    else {
        obj.stop(document.body);
    }
};
```

I've tried `""` and `function(){}` instead `null`, but those were not effective either. If I set the `onclick` event in the browser console, after I called `start`, it works.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. The code you've posted doesn't properly demonstrate your issue.

Comment: [Your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/4d8wj1t5/1/). But this approach makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I'm using a checkbox and accidentally put `this.value` in the if calling the start/stop instead of `this.checked`.

Answer (score 0):

`obj.stop(document.body)` is never run because `this.value` is always `true`. What you're looking for is `this.checked`.

Fixed code :

```
const MyObj = function(x) {
    this.x = x;
};
MyObj.prototype.start = function(el) {
    el.onclick = (function() {
        console.log(this.x);
    }).bind(this);
};
MyObj.prototype.stop = function(el) {
    el.onclick = null;
};

const obj = new MyObj("x");
document.getElementById("checkbox").onchange = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        obj.start(document.body);
    } else {
        obj.stop(document.body);
    }
};
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/t1hupbvg/) for a demo.

Answer (score -2):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).

```
el.addEventListener("click", someHandler);
// later...
el.removeEventListener('click', someHandler);
```

Note that `someHandler` must be the same object, both times. Don't use an inline function.

Comment: I thought about that, but I can't use it because I'm using a value from the constructor. I've updated my question.

Comment: This is better practice, but wouldn't solve the (non-existing) problem

Answer (score -2):

I've made my own version of an event handler:

```
var EventHandler = function(){}
EventHandler.prototype.events = [];
EventHandler.prototype.functions = [];
EventHandler.prototype.addEventListener = function(e,f,obj)   // start
{
    if (obj === undefined) obj = window;
    this.events.push(e);
    this.functions.push(f);
    obj.addEventListener(e,f);
};
EventHandler.prototype.removeEventListener = function(e,obj)   // stop
{
    if (obj === undefined) obj = window;
    var i = this.events.indexOf(event);
    if (i === -1)
    {
        return;
    }
    obj.removeEventListener(event,this.functions[i]);
    this.events.splice(i,1);
    this.functions.splice(i,1);
    //this.removeEventListener(e,obj);      // to remove multiple events of the same type
}
```

The problem you have is that only when it runs the start method does it actually add the onclick listener.

```
const MyObj = function(x) {
    this.x = x;
};
MyObj.prototype.start = function(el)
{
    var self = this;
    el.addEventListener("click",function()
    {
        console.log(self.x);
    });
    console.log("started");
    console.log(el);
};
MyObj.prototype.stop = function(el) {
    var self = this;
    el.removeEventListener("click",function()
    {
        console.log(self.x);
    });
    console.log("stopped");
};

var test = new MyObj(54);
test.start(document.getElementById("thing"));
```